# save jquery flip state into a php session variable?

Tags: php, jquery, session, slidetoggle, flip

I am using this tutorial http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/tryit.asp?filename=tryjquery_slide_toggle

Here is the code without the style.

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
$(document).ready(function()
{


$(".flip").click(function()
    {
    var panel = "open";
    $(".panel").slideToggle("slow");
    });
});
</script>
```

How would I go about saving the state of this so if I refreshed the page it would remain open or closed. I imagine a php session would be the correct way, but how do I write that in the javascript?

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Answer (score 0):

In JS:

```
var readWirite='write'; //or 'read'
$.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url:  "myPhpFile.php",
   data: "panel="+panel+"&readWrite="+readWrite;
   success: function(msg){
      if(msg == '1'){
        alert('Horay panel saved!');
      } else {
        $('#panelId').html(msg); //Write saved panel back to html 
      }
   }                       
});
```

In myPhpFile.php:

```
<?php
   if(!isset($_SESSION)) session_start();
   if(isset($_POST['readWrite']) && isset($_POST['panel'])){
      if($_POST['readWrite'] == 'write'){
          $result = '0'; 
          if($_SESSION['panel'] = $_POST['panel']) $result = '1';
          echo $result;
      } else if($_POST['readWrite'] == 'read') {
          echo $_SESSION['panel'];
      }
   }
?>
```